# How does CometD handle ports in long polling?

Tags: http, long-polling, cometd

Does a specific port handle all requests/responses from a client-side in **long polling** using CometD? If not how does it assign the ports for each request?

Answer (score 1):

A CometD client can use either HTTP or WebSocket as a transport.

In both cases, when the CometD client needs to open a new TCP connection to the server, the local port is assigned by the operative system in the range of the *ephemeral* ports (this varies from OS to OS).

Note that for HTTP, a CometD client typically opens at most 2 connections (one dedicated to long-polling, one for publishes).

For WebSocket, a CometD client opens just 1 connection.

On the server, a single port (the listening port) is used to accept incoming connections from CometD clients.